# Full outer join with different WHERE clauses in Knex.js for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, where-clause, knex.js

I try to get a single row with two columns showing aggregation results: one column should show the total sum based on one WHERE-clause while the other column should show the total sum based on a different WHERE clause.

**Desired output**:

```
amount_vic    amount_qld
100           70
```

In raw **PostgreSQL** I could write something like that:

```
select 
 sum(a.amount) as amount_vic, 
 sum(b.amount) as amount_qld 
from mytable a 
full outer join mytable b on 1=1
where a.state='vic' and b.state= 'qld'
```

**Question: How do I write this or a similar query that returns the desired outcome in ***knex.js***?** For example: the 'on 1=1' probably needs knex.raw() and I think the table and column aliases do not work for me and it always returns some errors.

One of my not-working-attempts in knex.js:

```
knex
        .sum({ amount_vic: 'a.amount' })
        .sum({ amount_qld: 'b.amount' })
        .from('mytable')
        .as('a')
        .raw('full outer join mytable on 1=1')
        .as('b')
        .where({
            a.state: 'vic',
            b.state: 'qld'
        })
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: FULL JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a FULL JOIN ON, a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING requiring some column(s) of the right/left/2 [sic] table(s) to be not NULL removes rows NULL-extended for columns of such table(s), ie leaves only LEFT/RIGHT/INNER [sic] JOIN ON rows, ie "turns FULL JOIN into LEFT/RIGHT/INNER JOIN". You have that. PS Similarly any outer join on true is thus like inner join except when exactly 1 table is empty.

Answer (score 1):

---

Disclaimer: this does not answer the Knex part of the question - but it is too long for a comment.

---

Although your current query does what you want, the way it is phrased seems suboptimal. There is not need to generate a self-cartesian product here - which is what `full join ... on 1 = 1` does. You can just use conditional aggregation.

In Postgres, you would phrase this as:

```
select 
    sum(amount) filter(where state = 'vic') amount_vic,
    sum(amount) filter(where state = 'qld') amount_qld
from mytable
where state in ('vic', 'qld')
```

I don't know Knex so I cannot tell how to translate the query to it. Maybe this query is easier for you to translate.

Comment: You are right and your query is absolutely better. But I think Knex.js does not allow conditional aggregations. I could write it as raw SQL, but my WHERE clause is horrible long/cumbersome due to some dynamic column/values that need to be constructed by knex.js...that would be painful to re-write that in vanilla javascript